# How to connect to Teradata in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, teradata

Could anybody give me sample code to connect to Teradata in Python Flask? I need to get all input values from a form, and save to Teradata table. Many thanks.

Comment: try the site here: https://fullstackfeed.com/a-simple-teradata-python-rest-api-interface-using-flask/

Comment: Or use flask-sqlalchemy with teradatasqlalchemy and teradatasql dialect.